# Assign proper velocity to pan gesture iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `tableView` with a `panGesture`.
 I am able to pan this `tableView` from bottom part of the screen vertically. 
However, I want the `panGesture` to continue with a certain velocity, to get a scrollView kind of effect while panning up/down.

What happens is that the `tableView` pans very quickly in upwards or downwards direction with no sign of stopping.

Here's what I have done so far :

```
 -(void)handlePanWithVelocity:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

    CGPoint displacement;
    CGPoint velocity = [gestureRecognizer velocityInView:self.mapView];
    switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:{
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:{
            CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
            displacement = (isVerticalPan) ? CGPointMake(0, translation.y) : CGPointMake(translation.x, 0);
            mytableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(displacement.x, displacement.y);
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
            displacement.y = displacement.y + velocity.y;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
                mytableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(displacement.x, displacement.y);
            }];
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:break;
    }

}
```

What can be done to improve the current behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you dont measure the time that it takes to move in the first place. Since velocity it x/t you need to adjust the duration of you UIView animation. You have to measure the time between the Pan Recognizer callbacks and then calculate the speed.

global variables:

```
double velocity;
NSDate *date;
```

and then:

```
 -(void)handlePanWithVelocity:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

    CGPoint displacement;
    CGPoint velocity = [gestureRecognizer velocityInView:self.mapView];
    switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:{
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:{


            CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
            displacement = (isVerticalPan) ? CGPointMake(0, translation.y) : CGPointMake(translation.x, 0);
            mytableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(displacement.x, displacement.y);

            if(date){
                double timePassed_ms = [date timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;
                velocity = displacement.y/timePassed_ms;
            } 


            date = [NSDate date];
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
            displacement.y = displacement.y + velocity.y;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
                mytableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, velocity);
            }];
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:break;
    }

}
```

I didnt test the code but you get the general idea.